# phonertc demo app only displays local video in firefox

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonertc

When using the demo app between ios and desktop browser, only the local video is displayed on each side.  Video and audio work fine for ios to ios connections.  Used the latest Cordova to build ios and browser platforms.  Tested on ios 8.1 and firefox 33.1.  Appreciate advice on how to troubleshoot.

Thanks.

Comment: seeing any errors at all ?

Comment: The Firefox browser console displays the following message from cordova.js: "Exception calling :: PhoneRTCPlugin :: call ::exception=TypeError: sessions[options[0].sessionKey] is undefined" line 830

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (PhoneRTC wouldn't work on Chrome). I fixed it by installing a web server (in my case WAMP) and moving my PhoneRTC folder in the www directory of WAMP. Then I run the project like so: http://localhost/[YourProjectName]. Hope this helps.